# Javamelody integration with tomcat, /monitoring link on the public server

Tags: jsp, tomcat

I would like to setup JavaMelody with Tomcat 8 on a production server with apache AJP connector. I don't want the **monitoring link** to be available on the public url of the applications. **I want to see the stats only by using the JavaMelody itself**.

I have the application uform deployed in the tomcat server. The app sits at `http://localip:8080/uform` and runs nicely.

The app is integrated with apache so I can see it by using the `http://www.uform.com` link.

In the web.xml of the app I have the following code added:

```
  <filter>
         <filter-name>monitoring</filter-name>
        <filter-class>net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringFilter</filter-class>
  </filter>
  <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>monitoring</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>
  <listener>
        <listener-class>net.bull.javamelody.SessionListener</listener-class>
  </listener>
```

I've put in the /lib folder of the app the jrobin and javamelody jars.
I can see the graphs when I navigate in the JavaMelody app (`http://localip:8080/javamelody` ) but i don't want to see the stats when I visit the link **http://www.uform.com/monitoring**

What should I do?
Thanks.
Rdu

Answer (score 1):

In case you don't want to hide the /monitoring url using apache httpd, but just want to restrict the access to the url, there are configurations possible, such as allowed-addr-pattern, security-constraint or authorized-users.
See this [chapter in the user guide](https://code.google.com/p/javamelody/wiki/UserGuide#16._Security).

Answer (score 0):

You can use mod_rewrite in apache (http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) to create a rewrite rule that returns a 404 when someone tries to access your monitoring url.  Something like:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName www.uform.com
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteRule ^.*monitoring.*$ [L,R=404]
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Very nice idea, but it doesn't work. Apache accepts the rule but somehow ignores it and passes the request to tomcat. I think in the web.xml file there should be something commented in order that the link /monitoring to become unavailable

Comment: @Rdu I tweaked the rewrite rule slightly